# UITabBarController Set a Default Tab in Swift Language

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that has 5 different view controllers attached to it. Each one has there own specific tab such as Home, Settings, etc. How can i set a certain tab to be the default tab when launched?

Comment: Are you creating this controller in Interface Builder or in code?

Comment: The Controller is in the Interface Builder, I have the TabBarController linked up to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason why you can't move your chosen first tab to be presented to the left most slot?

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = desiredIndex
```

or, if you're code is in a UITabBarConroller subclass, simply:

```
 selectedIndex = desiredIndex
```

should work.

Comment: Just Trying to Change it up a bit, but i could do that

Answer (score 0):

You could consider changing the tab in the app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (or whatever owns the tab bar controller) with code like this:

```
if let tabController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        tabController.selectedIndex = 1
    }
```